# What is the efficient way to get only first Lookupvalue from SpFieldLookupValueCollection in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I want to Access only first Lookupvalue of SpFieldLookupValueCollection presently I am doing something like this

```
            string abc = string.Empty;
            foreach (SPFieldLookupValue value in SpFieldLookupValueCollection)
            {
                abc = value.LookupValue;
                break;
            }
```

Am Fresher to sharepoint please tell me better and faster way to access lookup Values

Thank you

Comment: Add Book bookToDelete = Books.OrderBy(b => b.SomeDate).First();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SPFieldLookupValue fieldValue=SpFieldLookupValueCollection.FirstOrDefault();

and 

SpFieldLookupValueCollection.First();
```

this will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Linq query as follows,

`var firstElement = SpFieldLookupValueCollection.FirstOrDefault();`

Note: you will have to include `System.Linq;` namespace

Answer (score -1):

It's better to get the value of a specific column rather than retrieveing all columns.The following code should work for you.

```
string fieldValue  = "";

if (item["fieldname"] != null)
{
    var val= (SPFieldLookupValue)item["fieldname"];
    fieldValue = fieldValue .LookupValue;

}
```

Comment: Hi Swati, thank you for you answer,  i want to get only first value. How it is handled here?